# How to make grid squares change color?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am still a beginner and I am trying understand how to change the grid colors for my etch-a-sketch project. Some guidance would be wonderful.

I can get the background of the page to change color, I can also get the grid border to change color, however not the pocket of space in between the grids. I also can't workout how to leave a trail. Css only allows animation and hover, which doesn't leave a permanent trail. So, I know a function that stores the value.

Can someone please highlight which part my code is wrong and why it is wrong and if you have an online resource that I can read, so that I can create the function for leaving a trail and the changing color in each grid I would be forever grateful.

Here's my code:

```js
//first div
let container = document.createElement('div')
container.setAttribute('id', 'container');
container.classList.add("grid");
document.body.appendChild(container);



//second div

let containerGrid = document.createElement('div')
containerGrid.setAttribute('id', 'containerGrid');
containerGrid.classList.add("grids");
document.body.appendChild(containerGrid);

//button div
let buttonDiv = document.createElement('div')
buttonDiv.setAttribute('id', 'button');
buttonDiv.classList.add("button");
document.body.appendChild(buttonDiv);


//buttons//

const eraserButton = document.createElement('button');
eraserButton.textContent ="Eraser";
eraserButton.classList.add ("Eraser")
eraserButton.setAttribute('id', 'Eraser');
const clearButton = document.createElement('button');
clearButton.classList.add ("Clear")

clearButton.setAttribute('id', 'Clear');
clearButton.textContent ="Clear";

buttonDiv.appendChild(eraserButton);
buttonDiv.appendChild(clearButton);

//hover color event

function random (number) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (number +1));
}

const input = document.querySelectorAll('#col');

function rainbowColor () {
    const rndCol= 'rgb(' + random(255) + ',' + random(255) +',' + random (255) + ')';
containerGrid.col.style.BackgroundColor = rndCol;

}

input.onmouseover = (rainbowColor);

/*
const inputOne = document.querySelector('#color-picker');
inputOne.addEventListener('mouseover', e => {
    e.target.classList.add = ('color-picker');

});


const inputTwo = document.querySelector('#black-pick');
inputTwo.addEventListener('mouseover', e =>  {
    e.target.classList.add = ('black-pick');
});
*/
const btn = document.querySelector('#Eraser');
btn.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    console.log(e);
});

const btnTwo = document.querySelector('#Clear');
btn.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
   console.log(e);
});

//make grid 16*16

function makeCols (col) {
    for (let i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        const colDivs = document.createElement('div');
        colDivs.setAttribute('id', 'col');
        colDivs.classList.add('cols');
        colDivs.textContent ="";
        colDivs.style.border = ('solid');
        colDivs.style.display= ('grid');
        colDivs.style.padding = ('5px');
        containerGrid.appendChild(colDivs);
    }
}
makeCols (16);

function makeRows (rows) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
        const rowDivs = document.createElement('div');
        rowDivs.setAttribute('id', 'rows');
        rowDivs.classList.add('rows');
        rowDivs.style.border = ('solid');
        rowDivs.style.display= ('grid');
        rowDivs.style.padding = ('5px');
               containerGrid.appendChild(rowDivs);
    }
}
makeCols (16);
makeRows(16);
```

```css
.grid {

width:500px;

}

.grids {

    display: grid;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(8,1fr);
    grid-auto-rows:repeat(8, 1fr);
    padding: 50px 50px;
    margin-left:150px;
    height:100px;
    width:200px;
 }

.rows {
    height:10px;
    width:10px;
    grid-column-gap:10px;

}
.cols {
    height:10px;
    width:10px;
}

.palette.cols:hover {
   background-color:rrggbb; 
}


.col {
    background-color:black;
}

.rows {
    background-color: red, black, blue, yellow, purple, green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Etch-a-Sketch</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div id ="color-picker" class = "palette">
        <input type="color" name="Rainbow" id="rainbow-colors" value= "#e66465">
        <label for="Rainbow">Rainbow</label>
    </div>
        
    <div id = "black-pick" class = "black-color">
        <input type="color" name="Black" id="black-color" value="#rrggbb">
        <label for="Black">Black</label>
    </div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do now use the same ID for every element. IDs attributes are supposed to be unique for every element. Give them unique IDs: `'col' + i` and `'rows' + j` or `'row' + j`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Fixed in a couple steps**

1. Assign `onmouseover` *after* you create the HTML elements.
2. In the `onmouseover` handler, use the event parameter to get the element
3. You had a typo in the background color, it's `backgroundColor`, lower case first letter
4. I made the IDs unique
5. I changed the selector of your onmouseover handler to `.cols`
6. Loop through found elements and assign onmouseover handler

For anything else, see snippet below.

```js
//first div
let container = document.createElement('div')
container.setAttribute('id', 'container');
container.classList.add("grid");
document.body.appendChild(container);



//second div

let containerGrid = document.createElement('div')
containerGrid.setAttribute('id', 'containerGrid');
containerGrid.classList.add("grids");
document.body.appendChild(containerGrid);

//button div
let buttonDiv = document.createElement('div')
buttonDiv.setAttribute('id', 'button');
buttonDiv.classList.add("button");
document.body.appendChild(buttonDiv);


//buttons//

const eraserButton = document.createElement('button');
eraserButton.textContent ="Eraser";
eraserButton.classList.add ("Eraser")
eraserButton.setAttribute('id', 'Eraser');
const clearButton = document.createElement('button');
clearButton.classList.add ("Clear")

clearButton.setAttribute('id', 'Clear');
clearButton.textContent ="Clear";

buttonDiv.appendChild(eraserButton);
buttonDiv.appendChild(clearButton);

//hover color event

function random (number) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (number +1));
}

function rainbowColor (e) {
    const rndCol= 'rgb(' + random(255) + ',' + random(255) +',' + random(255) + ')';
    e.target.style.backgroundColor = rndCol;
}

/*
const inputOne = document.querySelector('#color-picker');
inputOne.addEventListener('mouseover', e => {
    e.target.classList.add = ('color-picker');

});


const inputTwo = document.querySelector('#black-pick');
inputTwo.addEventListener('mouseover', e =>  {
    e.target.classList.add = ('black-pick');
});
*/
const btn = document.querySelector('#Eraser');
btn.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    console.log(e);
});

const btnTwo = document.querySelector('#Clear');
btn.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
   console.log(e);
});

//make grid 16*16

function makeCols (col) {
    for (let i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        const colDivs = document.createElement('div');
        colDivs.setAttribute('id', 'col' + i);
        colDivs.classList.add('cols');
        colDivs.textContent ="";
        colDivs.style.border = ('solid');
        colDivs.style.display= ('grid');
        colDivs.style.padding = ('5px');
        containerGrid.appendChild(colDivs);
    }
}
makeCols (16);

function makeRows (rows) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
        const rowDivs = document.createElement('div');
        rowDivs.setAttribute('id', 'row' + j);
        rowDivs.classList.add('rows');
        rowDivs.style.border = ('solid');
        rowDivs.style.display= ('grid');
        rowDivs.style.padding = ('5px');
               containerGrid.appendChild(rowDivs);
    }
}

makeCols(16);
makeRows(16);

var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.cols');
for(var k=0; k<inputs.length; k++) {
    inputs[k].onmouseover = rainbowColor;
}
```

```css
.grid {

width:500px;

}

.grids {

    display: grid;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(8,1fr);
    grid-auto-rows:repeat(8, 1fr);
    padding: 50px 50px;
    margin-left:150px;
    height:100px;
    width:200px;
 }

.rows {
    height:10px;
    width:10px;
    grid-column-gap:10px;

}
.cols {
    height:10px;
    width:10px;
}

.palette.cols:hover {
   background-color:rrggbb; 
}


.col {
    background-color:black;
}

.rows {
    background-color: red, black, blue, yellow, purple, green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Etch-a-Sketch</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div id ="color-picker" class = "palette">
        <input type="color" name="Rainbow" id="rainbow-colors" value= "#e66465">
        <label for="Rainbow">Rainbow</label>
    </div>
        
    <div id = "black-pick" class = "black-color">
        <input type="color" name="Black" id="black-color" value="#rrggbb">
        <label for="Black">Black</label>
    </div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```